# Removing headers from response in Angular Observable

Tags: json, angular, amazon-web-services, model, observable

Working with AWS DynamoDB to return some film JSON data to my application. There can be multiple films so I need to use an array and iterate through it to display my film list. However, I'm getting an error stating that only arrays and iterables are allowed.

[image: error 1]

I've also console.logged the response, which is below.

[image: response]

As you can see, my response has a body and headers, the headers are needed for my http requests to prevent cors issues, but I'm now really struggling to break the data down to Items. I'm retrieving the data from a Lambda function with an observable called IFilm[].

[image: film service]

Above is my service code, which pipes the data to my dashboard component.

[image: dashboard component]

And the filmList populated in this function is what I'm trying to iterate through in my html using an *ngFor. When trying to use .body or the likes on the response, I receive this error.

[image: body does not exist]

I feel like I'm so close to cracking this, so any advice is appreciated and if any clarification is required just ask :)

Thanks.

[edit in case anyone suggests this]

I've also tried using next, complete, error in my .subscribe but had no luck.

[image: no]

[edit 2]

So I tried using response['body'] and received this message.

[image: error]

And I also tried using the second suggestion, changed some things around a little but now it's gone very weird.

[image: weird]

[edit 3]

Sorry my mistake, I had missed one of the changes. My service is now red line free, but the error about missing length, pop, concat, has moved to my dashboard component.

[image]

[edit 4]

Fixed it, for any future readers here's what I did. When making an API call to my Lambda function I had to have the headers and body returned. I was trying to take this data and pass it, both headers and body, into my IFilm model. Instead, what I needed to do was create an IResponse model, parse some of the data from that and then populate my IFilm[] using my IResponse.

[image: IResponse]
[image: IFilm]

And below is the code in my dashboard component for populating my IFilm array.

[image: getFilms]

Comment: try: `response['body']`

Answer (score 1):

Why are you set the _http, with the new HttpClient()? It is injected by Dependency Injection if you put the HttpClientModule into the AppModule imports array.

Also you specified the generic return type IFilm[] so if you get back a HttpResponse with a body parameter and IFilm[] in it you have to specify as a HttpResponse<IFilm[]>.
So the actual code is:

```
this._http.get<HttpResponse<IFilm[]>>(...)
```

Plus the return value of the getFilmList should be Observable<HttpResponse<IFilm[]>>.
More about the HttpResponse here: https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpResponse

[Update]
Then if you updated, you can get the films by response.body.

```
this.filmList = response.body;
```